Questions about focal_length, rvec, and tvec from camera calibration
I used images of the checkerboard to proceed with the camera calibration.
I am using PoE camera to estimate the distance from an object (actual size is known) to the camera by using focal length.
Here is the output.
Camera Calibration:  1.7443757332593848

Camera Matrix:
 [[1.60769726e+03 0.00000000e+00 9.52018792e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.60665029e+03 2.92296761e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]

Distortion Parameters:
 [[-0.21606616 -0.63180433 -0.00325319  0.00222699  1.98712916]]

Rotation Vectors:
 (array([[ 0.07224807],
       [-0.50125655],
       [-0.1803044 ]]), array([[ 0.09261887],
       [ 0.06385082],
       [-0.00816447]]), array([[ 0.08968368],
       [ 0.05769877],
       [-0.01871089]]), array([[9.03344928e-02],
       [1.21236810e-01],
       [2.69416301e-05]]), array([[0.11183268],
       [0.29111005],
       [0.03007957]]), array([[0.11217145],
       [0.42133195],
       [0.02784451]]), array([[0.14417592],
       [0.53619098],
       [0.04125443]]), array([[0.16017898],
       [0.67775563],
       [0.04417317]]), array([[ 0.04416578],
       [-0.02285857],
       [-0.01705777]]), array([[ 0.09415478],
       [-0.13700963],
       [-0.02052559]]), array([[ 0.09660401],
       [-0.27047429],
       [-0.02057789]]), array([[ 0.1023921 ],
       [-0.23873025],
       [-0.03277892]]), array([[ 0.10150192],
       [-0.35322471],
       [-0.07257268]]), array([[ 0.09091438],
       [-0.40158596],
       [-0.10816352]]), array([[ 0.06015935],
       [-0.50295236],
       [-0.12777835]]))

Translation Vectors:
 (array([[-0.0609731 ],
       [ 0.00573651],
       [ 0.39862613]]), array([[-0.1255173 ],
       [-0.00786904],
       [ 0.35559186]]), array([[-0.12519083],
       [-0.00685334],
       [ 0.353846  ]]), array([[-0.12417797],
       [-0.0180632 ],
       [ 0.41538341]]), array([[-0.10585784],
       [-0.01815088],
       [ 0.40054014]]), array([[-0.10077983],
       [-0.02083386],
       [ 0.40778494]]), array([[-0.1035432],
       [-0.020356 ],
       [ 0.4242453]]), array([[-0.10760302],
       [-0.03312439],
       [ 0.45943657]]), array([[-0.13239241],
       [-0.00820463],
       [ 0.33685892]]), array([[-0.11440255],
       [-0.00992325],
       [ 0.34370701]]), array([[-0.10157535],
       [-0.03602992],
       [ 0.32223598]]), array([[-0.12930068],
       [-0.00939119],
       [ 0.33570583]]), array([[-0.11115253],
       [-0.0047846 ],
       [ 0.30802406]]), array([[-0.14004492],
       [ 0.00104571],
       [ 0.33794211]]), array([[-0.05227404],
       [-0.01433328],
       [ 0.29691116]]))


I also used this image to calculate the camera's focal length by using 'focal_length = (actual_distance * image_object_height) / actual_object_height'. I got between 1250 - 1400 which is quite different from the value I got from the camera calibration.

Which focal length should I use to estimate the distance between the camera and an object (known size)?

Also, which rvec and tvec from the camera calibration should I use to estimate the 'world coordinate' of the object? or should I use cv2.solvePnP to get rvec and tvec for every frame of the live stream camera?



since you haven't presented the data you calibrate on, that puts the results of the calibration in question. -- lens distortion is unlikely to account for the differences in the calculated focal lengths

(1)
Looking the your camera image, I don't think we can ignore the distortion.
That is, estimating focal_length value under the assumption that camera has no distortion can not cause good accuracy.
And, I believe this is one of the main reasons why you are performing camera calibration.
If so, you should use the calibration result.
Of course, you should use the whole camera model (all intrinsic parameters) rather than just only focal_length.
(2)

rvec and tvec from the camera calibration

They are the information about relationship between camera and each checkerboard.
So, they are not necessary unless you want to know the positions of the checkerboard captured during calibration.
